# Elementor, ломается верстка из-за появляющегося тега <font color> в верстке

Tags: wordpress, elementor

В редакторе Элементора сайт смотрится как нужно, при просмотре изменений в опубликованном сайте в некоторых местах ломается верстка из-за тега `<font color>`, который относится толи к колонке, толи к секции, откуда он берется не могу понять. Если его удалить через `F12`, все выглядит как надо. Помогите, молю, уже целый день с этой проблемой мучаюсь((

[Страница сайта с проблемой](https://xn--21-6kcaak5cel6g.xn--p1ai/)

Блок №5, Специальные предложения

Кусок кода с проблемой

```html
<font color="#F5D9B0">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8af14ec elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-view-default elementor-position-top elementor-mobile-position-top elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon-box" data-id="8af14ec" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon-box.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
        <div class="elementor-icon-box-......
```

Comment: Нужно понимать откуда он берется. Может Вы скопировали и вставили его туда вместе с текстом, например.

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, какого еще "элемента"? См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/elementor/info

Comment: @simon В том то и проблема, что не знаю откуда он появляется, самое интересное что при просмотре html кода сайта, этого тега вообще нет, значит какой-то системный тег вордпресса или элементора, еще покопался, в стилях он указывается как я понял [стиль атрибутов], сам не особо разбираюсь в вп

Comment: @Sunnycove попробуйте сделать данную секцию с самого начала, не копируя элементы с текущей. Очень сомнительно что `font` добавляется именно посредством какого-то виджета элементора, так как это в принципе устаревший тег.

Comment: @Simon Уже пытался( та же проблема получается

Comment: Смотрите с каким конкретно блоком это случается, с заголовком или чем-то еще. Вряд ли обертка `font` появляется когда Вы на страницу просто секцию добавляете.

Comment: @simon Проверил, эта обертка появляется такое чувство что вообще рандомно, где то перед секцией, где то перед колонкой, где то в пустоте после колонок, даже присутствует перед тегами скрипта и стилей, с ума уже схожу с этой проблемой :'(